# GIT - Replacing Master branch with a newer branch

Tags: git

I have the following branch structure in my repository:
[image]

MATER is no longer needed so i created a new branch based it on it called 'OLD_MASTER' just in case we will ever need it. Now i want to replace MASTER with NEW_MASTER (Basically a rename and a removal of the previous MASTER) how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Delete current `MASTER` branch and create a new `MASTER` branch from `NEW_MASTER`. Then do force push to `remote/MASTER` (force push needed as MASTER history is changed).

```
$ git checkout NEW_MASTER      
$ git branch -D MASTER         # delete local MASTER

$ git checkout -b MASTER       # create & checkout a new MASTER from NEW_MASTER
$ git push -f origin MASTER    # force push, update remote MASTER
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this the following way:

1) Push your `NEW_MASTER` branch to the remote as `MASTER`, overwriting the branch which is currently there:

```
git push origin NEW_MASTER:MASTER
```

2) Next, delete your local `MASTER` branch:

```
git branch -d MASTER
```

3) Finally, bring in the updated remote `MASTER` branch via a fetch and checkout:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/MASTER
git checkout -b MASTER
```

Answer (score 1):

This, in theory, is a 3 step process:

Check out the "new master" branch

`$ git checkout new_master`

Delete the current master branch

`$ git branch -D master`

Create a new branch based on your current branch

`$ git checkout -b master`

**HOWEVER**

If the repo is shared by other or has a remote that others may have clone then you need to be careful. If no-one else is sharing this code then you should be fine to do this. If it's a big codebase then some further work in getting the old master back to how you want the new master to be.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i the solution i used was similar but instead of creating a new master branch i used 'reset --hard':

```
git checkout MASTER
git reset --hard NEW_MASTER (make MASTER branch point to HEAD of NEW_MASTER)
git push origin master:master -f
```